# Make a python py.test unit test run independantly of the location where py.test in executed?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Lets say  my code looks like this

```
import pytest
import json

@pytest.fixture
def test_item():
    test_item = json.load(open('./directory/sample_item_for_test.json','rb'))
    return test_item

def test_fun(test_document):
    assert  type(test_item.description[0]) == unicode
```

And I would like to run this test via Py.Test

If I run Py.test from the directory that it is in, it is fine. BUT if I run it from an above directory, it fails due to not being able to find 'sample_item_for_test.json'. Is there a way to make this test run correctly no matter where I execute Py.test?

Comment: Also note that `type(a) == b` is usually not what you want.  `isinstance(a, b)` is more idiomatic and will pass instances of subclasses as well.

Answer (score 2):

The magic attribute `__file__` is the path to the python file on the filesystem.  So, you can use that with some magic from `os` to get the current directory...

```
import pytest
import json
import os

_HERE = os.path.dirname(__file__)
_TEST_JSON_FILENAME = os.path.join(_HERE, 'directory', 'sample_item_for_test.json')

@pytest.fixture
def test_item():
    with open(_TEST_JSON_FILENAME, 'rb') as file_input:
        return json.load(file_input)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I migrated to py.test, I had a large set of legacy tests that were accustomed to being executed in the directory where the test file lives. Instead of tracking down every test failure, I added a pytest hook to my `conftest.py` to chdir to the test directory before each test starts:

```py
import os
import functools

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    """
    Execute each test in the directory where the test file lives.
    """
    starting_directory = os.getcwd()
    test_directory = os.path.dirname(str(item.fspath))
    os.chdir(test_directory)

    teardown = functools.partial(os.chdir, starting_directory)
    # There's probably a cleaner way than accessing a private member.
    item.session._setupstate.addfinalizer(teardown, item)
```